# from brownie import Token, accounts

Tags: tokens, brownie

Error is cannot find Token

Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name 'Token' from 'brownie

However Token JSON file exists

brownie bake token worked

Answer (score 0):

The docs aren't super clear about this, but they assume you have a `Token` contract defined.
`brownie bake token` will create this for you.

Comment: How do you get brownie to work. For some reason I have a new computer and cannot get brownie to work despite doing exactly the procedure. this all works                               python3 -m pip install --user pipx
python3 -m pipx ensurepath                                                                                                        pipx install eth-brownie                                                                                                                                            brownie - cannot run/find this program error message

Comment: Sometimes you need to restart your terminal or possibly log out and log back in

Comment: This worked, why it did not work several times before no idea.